# How meaningful are the results when you difference the time series dataset before clustering?

Tags: time-series, clustering, differencing

On a certain task where I need to perform K-Means Time Series Clustering with DTW algorithm, I would like to know how credible the results are when performing clustering on the original vs a dataset where first and second order differencing has been applied.

The original dataset is highly non-stationary and high correlation is present between the variables, so I decided to make the dataset stationary by differencing and only then perform clustering. On the differenced dataset , the silhouette score for `k=2`  is `0.68` and for `k=3` the score is `0.541`, while on the original dataset for `k=2` the score is `0.79`, and for `k=3` it is `0.434`. To summarize, I would like to know if:

1. Clustering results with non-stationary time series variables, even if clustering evaluation score is higher less preferable than clustering results with stationary variables?
2. I also would like to know if applying differencing is a common methodology for such tasks, as I have not found enough relevant literature.

If you can, please feel free to provide links to relevant publications. Thanks.

Comment: If you had some cointegrated series, you have removed their linkages by differencing. It could be natural to cluster a bunch of cointegrated series together, so clustering differenced series would be at a disadvantage. But this is just one aspect.

Comment: Thank you Richard, as I have had little support over this topic. On the other hand, the original un-differenced dataset is highly non-stationary and correlated, resulting in higher silhouette scores for a given cluster, but again I doubt that these results are more credible. From your experience, what would you recommend? Would using another option, such as clustering based on a certain decomposition solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I do not think I know enough about clustering to give any more concrete advice.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.